# I have a compiler error for Cmake, what should I do?

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, c++14, clion

For the past two days, I’ve been trying to start coding C++ on CLion and I’ve been running into problems with Cmake. Any recommendations would be appreciated. I tried deleting CLion and redownloading, and I've tried putting in different Cmake options I found online for C++. Any help would be appreciated.

[Short video of problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ubHujzTre6jJaW1nNpI7wO4Ax5BEZf27/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be **specific** about what you are trying to accomplish. Right now, your question is very broad. Please provide your C++/CMake code and any relevant **error** messages you may be encountering, and describe the **specific** steps you have taken to produce them. A video is helpful, but prefer to use **textual** code/logs and descriptions of the problem, as links to such videos may grow stale over time. Also, many viewers, such as myself, can't even view the video. Consider reading through the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install a compilers into command line as well. I guess the XCode is already installed. In addition you need to install command line tools via 'xcode-select --install' (maybe with sudo) to get while compilers toolchain in console too.
You can check if compiler works in terminal via e.g. 'clang --version' etc.
Anyway, please keep clear info about your dev. environment when you are asking..

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install XCode as XCode includes the compiler. 
[invalid active developer path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsLsk.jpg)